# Bionicle parts for own bionicle figure

Tags: bionicle, pick-a-brick

I need Bionicle parts to make my own Bionicle. 
Any good set recommendations? 
 Any LEGO set will do.  It does not have to be Bionicle.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many sets with big Bionicle part variety. I'm not sure what you are looking for. If you need specific parts I suggest to look for them on Bricklink. If you need to increase your Bionicle parts collection it might be better to look for local sales as Bionicle/Hero Factory are usually quite cheap.